# Time of day conversion into numeric and mutation in R

Tags: r

I am working in R. My data set has a column of times (hh:mm:ss). The column is listed as factors.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to get the diff() between the values in this column (that is, the difference between time1 and time2 in the same column). I can't do that with factors.

How would I convert the times to another form that will allow me to calculate the difference in times within the same column? 
Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: You can use `hms()` from `lubridate` and then `difftime()`.

Comment: Try the `times` function from the  `chron` package.  You should already have it installed.

Comment: If I use the following: test <- hms(my_df$time, quiet=FALSE, roll = FALSE), then I get the time hours, min and seconds. difftime() is not a function in lubridate, did you mean a different function? .....As for the second comment, I also cannot find the 'time' function in the chron package details....thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1,2,3,4)
time1 <- hms(factor(c("09:00:01","04:02:50","10:30:21","11:15:25")))
time2 <- hms(factor(c("00:00:01","01:02:00","09:30:11","14:15:25")))

df<-data.frame(id, time1, time2)

df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 summarize(t_diff = time1 - time2)

     t_diff
1  9H 0M 0S
2 3H 0M 50S
3 1H 0M 10S
4 -3H 0M 0S
```

Answer (score -1):

taking what you've suggested:

```
x <- factor(c("12:34:56", "12:35:45", "12:48:00"))
y <- factor(c("12:42:56", "13:22:41", "17:11:21"))

## convert to time
x <- strptime(x, format = "%H:%M:%S")
y <- strptime(y, format = "%H:%M:%S")

## now you want a vector of differences
difftime(y,x, units="hours")
Time differences in hours
[1] 0.1333333 0.7822222 4.3891667
```

Edit: I misread your question. You want differences *within* one column. Remember that you'll end up with the [fencepost problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) because your output will have one fewer rows than your column. Try

```
diff.difftime(x)
Time differences in seconds
[1]  49 735
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help. After using this code (which I thought was successful) I am realizing that using hms(), the time changes. For example, if I bring in my data$time before running it through hms(), the first returned time is: 08:08:48.63. If I run the SAME vector through hms(), it returns 11H 18M 48.63S. Does changing a character to a period alter the time in some way? Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated!